# Pandas to_csv script modifying numbers to long float numbers when it shouldn't be

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

The pandas script below keeps modifying my data exported to CSV when it shouldn't be.
If you compare the original file to the modified `testing2.csv` you'll see that numbers like: `0.357` from the first line turn into: `0.35700000000000004` yet on line 2 the number `0.1128` doesn't change at all...

It should **NOT** be modifying these numbers, they should all remain as they are.

#### testing.py

```
import re
import pandas
# each block in the text file will be one element of this list
matchers = [[]]
i = 0 
with open('testing.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        # Blocks are seperated by blank lines
        if len(line) == 0:
            i += 1
            matchers.append([])
            # assume there are always two blank lines between items 
            # and just skip to the lext line
            infile.next()
            continue
        matchers[i].append(line)


# This regular expression matches the variable number of students in each block
studentlike = re.compile('(\d+) (.+) (\d+/\d+)')
# These are the names of the fields we expect at the end of each block
datanames = ['Data', 'misc2', 'bla3']
# We will build a table containing a list of elements for each student
table = []
for matcher in matchers:
    # We use an iterator over the block lines to make indexing simpler
    it = iter(matcher)
    # The first two elements are match values
    m1, m2 = it.next(), it.next()
    # then there are a number of students
    students = []
    for possiblestudent in it:
        m = studentlike.match(possiblestudent)
        if m:
            students.append(list(m.groups()))
        else:
            break
    # After the students come the data elements, which we read into a dictionary
    # We also add in the last possible student line as that didn't match the student re
    dataitems = dict(item.split() for item in [possiblestudent] + list(it))
    # Finally we construct the table
    for student in students:
        # We use the dictionary .get() method to return blanks for the missing fields
        table.append([m1, m2] + student + [dataitems.get(d, '') for d in datanames])

textcols = ['MATCH2', 'MATCH1', 'TITLE01', 'MATCH3', 'TITLE02', 'Data', 'misc2', 'bla3']
csvdata = pandas.read_csv('testing.csv')
textdata = pandas.DataFrame(table, columns=textcols)

# Add any new columns
newCols = textdata.columns - csvdata.columns
for c in newCols:
    csvdata[c] = None

mergecols = ['MATCH2', 'MATCH1', 'MATCH3']
csvdata.set_index(mergecols, inplace=True, drop=False)
textdata.set_index(mergecols, inplace=True,drop=False)
csvdata.update(textdata)
csvdata.to_csv('testing2.csv', index=False)
```

#### testing.csv

- http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HxVE0nA0 (Uploaded because of file size)

#### testing.txt

```
MData (N/A)
DMATCH1
3 Tommy 144512/23332
1 Jim 90000/222311
1 Elz M 90000/222311
1 Ben 90000/222311
Data $50.90
misc2 $10.40
bla3 $20.20


MData (B/B) 
DMATCH2
4 James Smith 2333/114441
4 Mike 90000/222311
4 Jessica Long 2333/114441
Data $50.90
bla3 $5.44
```

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

(The above example recreates the issue 100% perfectly. Took me forever to find out what was causing this problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try this :)

```
csvdata = pandas.read_csv('testing.csv', dtype={'TITLE5' : 'object', 'TITLE5.1' : 'object', 'TITLE5.2' : 'object', 'TITLE5.3' : 'object'})
```

Comment: Storing numbers as objects doesn't seem like a forward-looking solution. Unless you plan to treat these numbers as string, never using their actual values, you had better use a solution that treats them as floats. @TomAugspurger's solution seems like a better compromise.

Comment: @DanAllan His option's aren't working for me, this option works, you really shouldn't be downvoting a working answer.

Comment: Did he really downvote it? Surly a downvote is only justified if my attempt to help someone was in fact not an attempt to help someone...

Comment: In my opinion, is it a *very bad idea* to load numerical data as objects, especially if only for cosmetic reasons. If you try to use numerical functions on that data, you'll run into [this confusing numpy bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/1611) that comes up here often. I used my downvote to un-promote this problematic approach; putting a chink in AEA's reputation was not the point. I appreciate AEA's good faith and will concede that his answer might be useful to someone, even if I disagree in this case. Too late to un-downvote.

Comment: @DanAllan If he edits his post you can turn it back to an upvote or no vote. However, back to the problem in question the code provided by TomAugspurger doesn't fit my needs as it also turns some of my columns what have 8 decimal place floats or my columns that have 1 or 2 decimal point floats into 4 decimal places floats, converting as mattexx showed does nothing in my code (I'm unable to get what he said working)... so what other solutions are there?

Comment: As annoying as those stray decimal places are, they are an unavoidable artifact of storing base 10 numbers in binary. Usually I ignore them, or truncate them as Tom suggested. Is there a reason that you need to store and retrieve the exact number of decimal places? Please explain more about what you want to do with the data -- the big picture.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a precision issue.

Try changing your `to_csv` lines to include the argument `float_format='%.4f'` which will round things to 2 decimal places.

Comment: The problem with this is I have some numbers that are small floats (1dp or 2dp) which I want them to stay 1 or 2dp.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas supports two basic numeric types, Int64 and Float64. Float64 will not represent decimal values exactly, because it is a floating-point type. Your options are

1. Specify `float_format` as suggested by @TomAugspurger (this can be done column-wise or for the whole dataframe
2. Convert your column dtype to object

Option 2 can be done liuke this:

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].astype(object)
```

Comment: Option 2 doesn't seem to work for me, are you able to get it working in my example?

Comment: Your example doesn't run in my environment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 41, in <module>
    dataitems = dict(item.split() for item in [possiblestudent] + list(it))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #2 has length 3; 2 is required

Comment: Unsure why, it must be something to do with the `\r` and `\n`'s