# Pandas to_dict unwantedly modifying float numbers

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, floating-point

My code below takes in CSV data and uses pandas `to_dict()` function as one step in converting the data to JSON. **The problem is it is modifying the float numbers (e.g. 1.6 becomes 1.6000000000000001).** I am not concerned about the loss of accuracy, but because users will see the change in the numbers, it looks amateurish.

I am aware:

- this is something that has come up before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912611/pandas-script-modifying-numbers-to-long-float-numbers-when-it-shouldnt-even-be), but it was two years ago, was not really answered in a great way,
- also I have an additional complication: the data frames I am looking to convert to dictionaries **could be any combination of datatypes**

As such the issue with the previous solutions are:

1. **Converting all the numbers to objects only works if you don't need to (numerically) use the numbers**. I want the option to calculate sums and averages which reintroduces the addition decimal issue.
2. **Force rounding of numbers to x decimals will either reduce accuracy or add additional unnecessary 0s** depending on the data the user provides

#### My question:

Is there a better way to ensure the numbers are not being modified, but are kept in a numeric datatype? Is it a question of changing how I import the CSV data in the first place? Surely there is a simple solution I am overlooking?

Here is a simple script that will reproduce this bug:

```
import pandas as pd

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

CSV_Data = "Index,Column_1,Column_2,Column_3,Column_4,Column_5,Column_6,Column_7,Column_8\nindex_1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8\nindex_2,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8\nindex_3,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,3.6,3.7,3.8\nindex_4,4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4,4.5,4.6,4.7,4.8"

input_data = StringIO(CSV_Data)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(path = input_data, header = 0, sep=',', index_col=0, encoding='utf-8')
print(df.to_dict(orient = 'records'))
```

Comment: Why not use `df.to_json(orient = 'records')`, if end objective is to use json?

Comment: @JohnGalt Basically, in order to allow the dynamic nesting of columns, the dictionary I create using to_dict is inserted into a larger dictionary I am building up, which at the end gets dumped to a JSON.

Comment: you could use `pd.io.json.dumps(nested_dicts_with_pd_objects)`, does that work for you? Ideally, it ought not to introduce rounding scenario.

Comment: I might be misinterpreting your answer, but it is not the 'dumping to JSON' part that causes the issue, it is the creation of the dictionary. Unless there is a way build up JSON objects directly in Python?

Comment: In the dicts, values could be shown with extended decimals,when you use `pd.io.json.dumps(nested_dicts_with_pd_objects)`, the user will not see extended decimals. You may want to add detailed example?

Comment: what about `df.astype(object).to_dict('r')`?

Comment: @JohnGalt Actually that does seem to work - are you able to provide more detail on what this is actually doing? Is it just rounding to 10 decimal places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `pd.io.json.dumps` to handle nested dicts with pandas objects.

Let's create a `summary` dict with dataframe records and custom metric.

```
In [137]: summary = {'df': df.to_dict(orient = 'records'), 'df_metric': df.sum() / df.min()}

In [138]: summary['df_metric']
Out[138]:
Column_1    9.454545
Column_2    9.000000
Column_3    8.615385
Column_4    8.285714
Column_5    8.000000
Column_6    7.750000
Column_7    7.529412
Column_8    7.333333
dtype: float64

In [139]: pd.io.json.dumps(summary)
Out[139]: '{"df":[{"Column_7":1.7,"Column_6":1.6,"Column_5":1.5,"Column_4":1.4,"Column_3":1.3,"Column_2":1.2,"Column_1":1.1,"Column_8":1.8},{"Column_7":2.7,"Column_6":2.6,"Column_5":2.5,"Column_4":2.4,"Column_3":2.3,"Column_2":2.2,"Column_1":2.1,"Column_8":2.8},{"Column_7":3.7,"Column_6":3.6,"Column_5":3.5,"Column_4":3.4,"Column_3":3.3,"Column_2":3.2,"Column_1":3.1,"Column_8":3.8},{"Column_7":4.7,"Column_6":4.6,"Column_5":4.5,"Column_4":4.4,"Column_3":4.3,"Column_2":4.2,"Column_1":4.1,"Column_8":4.8}],"df_metric":{"Column_1":9.4545454545,"Column_2":9.0,"Column_3":8.6153846154,"Column_4":8.2857142857,"Column_5":8.0,"Column_6":7.75,"Column_7":7.5294117647,"Column_8":7.3333333333}}'
```

Use, `double_precision` to alter the maximum digit precision of doubles.
Notice. `df_metric` values.

```
In [140]: pd.io.json.dumps(summary, double_precision=2)
Out[140]: '{"df":[{"Column_7":1.7,"Column_6":1.6,"Column_5":1.5,"Column_4":1.4,"Column_3":1.3,"Column_2":1.2,"Column_1":1.1,"Column_8":1.8},{"Column_7":2.7,"Column_6":2.6,"Column_5":2.5,"Column_4":2.4,"Column_3":2.3,"Column_2":2.2,"Column_1":2.1,"Column_8":2.8},{"Column_7":3.7,"Column_6":3.6,"Column_5":3.5,"Column_4":3.4,"Column_3":3.3,"Column_2":3.2,"Column_1":3.1,"Column_8":3.8},{"Column_7":4.7,"Column_6":4.6,"Column_5":4.5,"Column_4":4.4,"Column_3":4.3,"Column_2":4.2,"Column_1":4.1,"Column_8":4.8}],"df_metric":{"Column_1":9.45,"Column_2":9.0,"Column_3":8.62,"Column_4":8.29,"Column_5":8.0,"Column_6":7.75,"Column_7":7.53,"Column_8":7.33}}'
```

You could use `orient='records/index/..'` to handle dataframe -> to_json construction.

```
In [144]: pd.io.json.dumps(summary, orient='records')
Out[144]: '{"df":[{"Column_7":1.7,"Column_6":1.6,"Column_5":1.5,"Column_4":1.4,"Column_3":1.3,"Column_2":1.2,"Column_1":1.1,"Column_8":1.8},{"Column_7":2.7,"Column_6":2.6,"Column_5":2.5,"Column_4":2.4,"Column_3":2.3,"Column_2":2.2,"Column_1":2.1,"Column_8":2.8},{"Column_7":3.7,"Column_6":3.6,"Column_5":3.5,"Column_4":3.4,"Column_3":3.3,"Column_2":3.2,"Column_1":3.1,"Column_8":3.8},{"Column_7":4.7,"Column_6":4.6,"Column_5":4.5,"Column_4":4.4,"Column_3":4.3,"Column_2":4.2,"Column_1":4.1,"Column_8":4.8}],"df_metric":[9.4545454545,9.0,8.6153846154,8.2857142857,8.0,7.75,7.5294117647,7.3333333333]}'
```

In essence, `pd.io.json.dumps` - converts arbitrary object recursively into JSON, which internally uses [ultrajson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson)

Answer (score 1):

I need to make `df.to_dict('list')` with right float numbers. But `df.to_json()` doesn't support `orient='list'` yet. So I do following:

```
 list_oriented_dict = {
    column: list(data.values())
    for column, data in json.loads(df.to_json()).items()
}
```

Not the best way, but it works for me. Maybe some one has a more elegant solution?