# Python Dictionary Values into Key and Append other keys

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a python DataFrame with the following:

```
myDF = pd.DataFrame({"COLUMN_NAME": ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"],
"RULE_1": ["NULL", "DUPLICATE", "TEXT-ONLY", "INTEGER-ONLY"],
"RULE_2": ["DUPLICATE", np.nan, "DUPLICATE", np.nan] })
```

How can I convert this into a dictionary that looks like that:

```
my_dict = {"Col1": ["NULL", "DUPLICATE"], "Col2": ["DUPLICATE"], "Col3": ["TEXT-ONLY", "DUPLICATE"], "Col4": ["INTEGER-ONLY"]}
```

I am stuck doing multiple loops but not really finding a solution.

```
final_rules_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k in rule_dict:
    row_dict = rule_dict[k]
    for k in row_dict:
        col_name = k
        if col_name == "COLUMN_NAMES":
            final_rules_dict[col_name].append()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works with the format you have given us

```
import json
myDF = pd.DataFrame({"COLUMN_NAME": ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"],
"RULE_1": ["NULL", "DUPLICATE", "TEXT-ONLY", "INTEGER-ONLY"],
"RULE_2": ["DUPLICATE", np.nan, "DUPLICATE", np.nan] })

myDF = myDF.T.reset_index(drop=True)
myDF.columns = myDF.iloc[0]
{
    col: [x for x in rows if x is not None] for col, rows in json.loads(pd.io.json.dumps(myDF[1:].to_dict(orient='list'))).items()
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the purpose of pd.io.json.dumps?

Comment: Is there a way to not include Null values in the lists from each key?

Comment: @matt.aurelio changed it to remove the null values. Not sure about the pd.io, took it from [here and it worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36695359/pandas-to-dict-unwantedly-modifying-float-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare your empty dict:

```
my_dict = {"Col1": [], "Col2": [], "Col3": [], "Col4": []}
```

based on `"COLUMN_NAME"` field.

Then you can iterate over the `myDF` keys (ignoring the `"COLUMN_NAME"` field ofc) and for each of those keys `rule_key` you can write something that looks like:

```
for i, my_dict_key in enumerate(myDF["COLUMN_NAME"]):
    my_dict[my_dict_key].append(myDF[rule_key][i])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
d = myDF.set_index('COLUMN_NAME').T.to_dict()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I used your approach to get the dictionary plus some more transformations without null values.

```
from collections import defaultdict

myDF2 = myDF.T.reset_index(drop=True)

myDF2.columns = myDF2.iloc[0]

myDF3 = myDF2[1:]

dfdict = defaultdict(list)
for (group, col), rule in myDF3.stack().items():
    dfdict[col].append(rule)

dfdict
```